# How to convert from string to date on android?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

Hello I want to convert from string to date(HH:mm) on android.

first I search how to convert from string to date.

I try this

```
String start = "16:00";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.KOREA);
Date d = format.parse(start);
```

but d is value `Thu Jan 01 16:00:00 GMT+09 00 1970` 
I want only `16:00` data format.

and I second try

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(start);
```

but date is value `Thu Jan 01 16:00:00 GMT+09:00 1970`

how to convert from string to date on android?

Comment: "I want only 16:00 data format." You've got a `Date`. A `Date` doesn't have a particular format. If you want to convert a `Date` to a `String` in a particular way, use `SimpleDateFormat` again, this time to format instead of to parse.

Comment: What you really want to get in the end? If the Date, then date can't have only the time part, it has to be full date in any case. If you want to get only the time, like hours and minutes value, then you can first convert it to Date as you already did, and then extract hours value and minutes value from it.

Comment: If you can live with a (good) third-party library, look into [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Use the `LocalTime` class from there and its `parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a **Date** object.

Those contain a TIMESTAMP and a DATE part.

You leave out the DATE part in your code; thus it gets defaulted.

In other words: what you are doing doesn't real sense!

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();  

String reportDate = df.format(today);

System.out.println("Report Date: " + reportDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String start = "16:00";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String date= formatter.format(start); //the result
```

Note: here you are making the same string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateStr = "03/26/2012 11:49:00 AM";

SimpleDateFormat dateForm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");

Date convertedDate = new Date();

try {

    convertedDate = dateForm.parse(dateStr);

} catch (ParseException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Prints:

Mon Mar 26 11:49:00 EEST 2012

or

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

String nowDate="20130917121823";

Date date = (Date) format .parse(nowDate);